# Old code running when deploying apk

Tags: java, android

I have an application that comes baked onto about 10 unrooted device OS's. Located in /system/priv-app.
Sometimes when debugging the app the old code is running instead of the modified one, even though a new apk is built and deployed.
Any idea as to what may cause this?
Working with Eclipse Kepler.

Comment: may be you have not imported project into the workspace. Check and import it into workspace rather than working on project kept in system

Comment: If the initalize process did fail, the system uses the previous version of apk file.

Comment: clean your project before running the code. uninstall the old app from the device, helps me everytime

Comment: Tried cleaning & uninstalling old app (well, uninstalling updates since it's a system app) - hasn't helped..
Even stranger: I've installed installed the first update (lets call it v1.1) changing a log to "v 1.1", uninstalled, changed said log to "v1.2" and installed v1.2 - and the log output is "v1.1".

Answer (score 0):

Had the same in Android Studio. Clean caches and restart your environment was the only solution I found.